# Setup UndoManager in NSView/NSViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to setup undo operations in my custom text view. My app structure is pretty simple - the default macOS app in XCode (not document based app). I have the following subclasses

`class TextViewController: NSViewController`
`class TextView: NSView`

At the end of TextViewController's viewDidLoad(), I ask it to `becomeFirstResponder()`

I also have a custom TextController class that manages the text. In my TextView, I have the following override

```
var undoManager: UndoManager? {
  textController?.undoManager
}
```

and in TextViewController's viewDidLoad, I have

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  let undoManager = UndoManager()
  textController.undoManager = undoManager

  textView.textController = textController
}
```

When entering text, I register a undo operation and set it's action name. However, the undo menu item does not become active (nor does it's action name change).

I've tried to override func undo in TextView with

```
@objc func undo(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
   undoManager?.undo()
}

@objc func redo(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
   undoManager?.redo()
}
```

Now, the undo menu item is always active (irrespective of if an undo operation has been registered). The undo/redo actions work correctly (if an undo or redo operation is available). But, the action name in the menu is never updated to "Undo Typing".

I guess the undo/redo work because of the overrides, but, the undoManager is not properly hooked up to the responder chain. How do I properly set this up to have the action names updated as well?

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic but what do you mean with "I ask it to becomeFirstResponder()"?

Comment: @Willeke I just call `becomeFirstResponder()` at the end of viewDidLoad(). The view then acceptsFirstResponder status.

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder()`, read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The steps outlined in [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68531?answerId=198115022#198115022) at Apple's Dev forums worked for me.

1. Setup a custom subclass of NSWindowController. In main.xib, set this subclass to be the window controller (instead of NSWindowController).
2. Verify that the subclass is the delegate of the contained NSWindow.
3. Setup a UndoManager() in the subclass. Override NSWindow delegate method `func windowWillReturnUndoManager(_ window: NSWindow) -> UndoManager?` and return the `UndoManager` that was setup in the subclass.

With this, undo/redo should work without having to override func's `undo()` or `redo()`. Action names also work fine.